# Refresh Excel 2013 from vbscript fails because of negative number format issue

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an MS Excel 2013 file containing a PowerPivot Data Model. The model is based on several text files (CSV files). The files are updated every night automatically. After these files update, the MS Excel file should be updated as well.

I open the MS Excel file and hit the "Refresh All" Button, everything works as expected. Of course this task should be automated. For this purpose I programmed a small vbscript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell, objShortCut, objFSO, objFile, objXLApp, objXLWB
Dim strShortCut

strShortCut = "\\myserver\share\Dashboard.lnk"

Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortCut(strShortCut)
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(objShortCut.TargetPath)

if (objFile.attributes and 1) then
   'File is read only. make it read/write-able
   objFile.attributes = objFile.attributes - 1
end if


' This is the interesting part
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXLApp.Visible = True
WScript.Echo "Excel Started"
objXLApp.Calculation = -4135
Set objXLWB = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(objShortCut.TargetPath)
WScript.Echo "Dashboard Opened"
objXLWB.Model.Initialize
WScript.Echo "Model Initialized"
objXLWB.Model.Refresh
WScript.Echo "Model Refreshed"
objXLApp.Calculation = -4105
objXLWB.save
WScript.Echo "Workbook saved"
objXLWB.close (false)
objXLApp.Quit
WScript.Echo "Excel closed"

if (not (objFile.attributes and 1)) then  
   'File is read/write. Make it read-only.
   objFile.attributes = objFile.attributes + 1
end if

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShortCut = Nothing
Set objXLApp = Nothing
Set objXLWB = Nothing
```

This script updates the data, but some columns in the text files contain numbers with trailing minus signs (for negative numbers). These columns are treated as text and therefore successive calculations on these columns fail.

This is not a problem if I refresh the MS Excel files by hand as described above. What's the difference from running Excel through a vbscript or "normally"?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 version of Excel installed? I have 3 versions and the Excel created by vbs on my computer always the oldest version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately this is not the reason. There is only one Version of Excel installed and the script starts the correct Version (I double-checked it).

Comment: What if you add `objXLWB.Worksheets(i).UsedRange.NumberFormat = "General"` (or the affected Range) to force the formatting? Excel from vbs may not have data-type auto-detect? I only have Excel up to 2010.

Comment: PatricK,this would not help - the data is not in an Excel Worksheet. It is in the Data Model (The in-Memory Engine).What I've done now is the following:
I created two xls files. One imports the data into the data model using the Excel Text Import Wizard. The other file imports the data into the data model using the PowerPivot Import wizard. If I refresh both files with the scipt posted above, the first file Fails with the same error (Numbers are not treated as numbers). The second file goes as expected.

Comment: The reason for the above behavior is, that starting MS Excel through a vbscript opens it with american regional settings. Refreshing the model will though import the data using american conventions (for decimal separator, negative sign,...) and not local ones. AFAIK there is no way to change this for the running instance. Suggestion for a workaround: put the code from the vbscript to an excel macro which triggers automatically when this excel file is opened and run it from the task scheduler...